# How make work import of python26.zip on windows

Tags: python, installation, embedding

I need to deploy a embeded version of python26.

I have it working under windows folowing the setup of http://www.portablepython.com/.

However after [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/789598/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-build-python26-zip-for-embedded-distribution) I try to pack everything into a zip file, and left out python.exe, python26.dll. However, that not work if python is not pre-installed.

Also, I try pre-compilling everything with `python -m compileall .`, but not do the trick.

When run python this way, this is the error:

> 'import site' failed; use -v for
>   traceback

This is the traceback:

```
# installing zipimport hook
import zipimport # builtin
# installed zipimport hook
# zipimport: found 1283 names in D:\Bajados\Adobe\python26.zip
'import site' failed; traceback:
ImportError: No module named site
```

I want to know the inner details that could make this work.

Comment: As reference, tortoiseHG do this...

Answer (score 0):

[Py2EXE](http://www.py2exe.org/) will do this for you, it fits nicely with `distutils`, so with a couple dozen lines of declaration in `setup.py` you'll get a nice windows application package without any python dependencies. Also, you can integrate further with [Innosetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) which gives you a great single-file-installer package.

Comment: I can't use that way. I have a windows embeded web server that use python. Is not a python app to be deployed, is a windows app that use python (like tortoise hg)

Comment: what way do you use it? I can't rellay tell from the question and your comment. As far as I can see there's no contradiction between a py2exe-type deployment and a portable python installation (the latter one being of course more generic). Whats your use case? (And sorry, I don't want to dissect tortoise-hg to understand)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps look into the flag Py_NoSiteFlag = 1;